# Form getting submitted even after using preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I am submitting a form in  ajax. I used certain validation for input format like time and phone no validation etc. But it submits the form after validation. I did use preventDefault() to prevent form submission but it doesn't work.

```
$("#sche_inter_form").submit(function(e) {
  if ($("#inter_name").val() === "") {
    $("#inter_name").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (($("#inter_date").val() === "") || (!(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/).test($("#inter_date").val()))) {
    $("#inter_date").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if (($("#inter_hr").val() === "") || (!(/^((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(:|\s)([0-5][0-9])$/).test($("#inter_hr").val()))) {
    $("#inter_hr").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  if ($("#inter_mr").val() === "") {
    $("#inter_mr").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  e.preventDefault();
  var candidate_id = $('#candidate_id').val();
  var profile_id = $('#profile_id').val();

  var date, time, inter_name, meridian, dataString;
  var inter_name = $('#inter_name').val();
  var date = $('#inter_date').val();
  var time = $('#inter_hr').val();
  var meridian = $('#inter_mr').val();
  var dataString = 'inter_name=' + inter_name + '&inter_date=' + date + '&inter_time=' + time + '&inter_meridian=' + meridian + '&candidate_id=' + candidate_id + '&profile_id=' + profile_id;
  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/schedule_interview",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Interview Scheduled Successfully");
    }
  });
});
```

This is my form

```
<form id = "sche_inter_form">
    <div class = "form-group">
        <input type = "text" id = "inter_name" placeholder = "Name of interviewer" required></input>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <b><p id = "schedule_text">Interview Schedule session</p></b>
    </div>

    <input type="hidden" id="candidate_id"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="profile_id"/>

    <div class = "form-group form-inline">
        <input type = "text" id = "inter_date" placeholder = "dd/mm/yyyy" required></input>
        <input type = "text" id = "inter_hr"   placeholder = "hh:mm" required></input>
        <input type = "text" id = "inter_mr" placeholder = "AM/PM" required></input>
    </div>

    <div class = "form-group">
        <input type = "submit" class ="btn btn-primary" value = "Schedule"></input>
    </div>



</form>
```

Comment: put the preventdefault directly after your submit method, do your validation after that or whatever and then submit();

Comment: Bind click event to submit button and do preventDefault.

Comment: try return false; instead of preventDefault.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent default behavior of submit button.
Try with below code

```
$("#sche_inter_form").submit(function(e){
```

replace with

```
$(".btn-primary").click(function(e){
```

You can add 'id' attribute to your submit button and use in above code instead of 'class'.

Answer (score 0):

`inputs` don't need closing tag. Remove `</input>` from your html and use `e.preventDefault();` only once. If you want to prevent form submit in some condition use `return false`

```js
$("#sche_inter_form").submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if ($("#inter_name").val() === "") {
    $("#inter_name").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
  }
  if (($("#inter_date").val() === "") || (!(/^(0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](19|20)\d\d+$/).test($("#inter_date").val()))) {
    $("#inter_date").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
  }
  if (($("#inter_hr").val() === "") || (!(/^((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))(:|\s)([0-5][0-9])$/).test($("#inter_hr").val()))) {
    $("#inter_hr").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
  }
  if ($("#inter_mr").val() === "") {
    $("#inter_mr").css({
      "border-bottom": " 1px solid #dd4b39"
    });
  }
  var candidate_id = $('#candidate_id').val();
  var profile_id = $('#profile_id').val();

  var date, time, inter_name, meridian, dataString;
  var inter_name = $('#inter_name').val();
  var date = $('#inter_date').val();
  var time = $('#inter_hr').val();
  var meridian = $('#inter_mr').val();
  var dataString = 'inter_name=' + inter_name + '&inter_date=' + date + '&inter_time=' + time + '&inter_meridian=' + meridian + '&candidate_id=' + candidate_id + '&profile_id=' + profile_id;
  $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    url: "/schedule_interview",
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    },
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      alert("Interview Scheduled Successfully");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="sche_inter_form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" id="inter_name" placeholder="Name of interviewer" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <b><p id = "schedule_text">Interview Schedule session</p></b>
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" id="candidate_id" />
  <input type="hidden" id="profile_id" />

  <div class="form-group form-inline">
    <input type="text" id="inter_date" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" required>
    <input type="text" id="inter_hr" placeholder="hh:mm" required>
    <input type="text" id="inter_mr" placeholder="AM/PM" required>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Schedule">
  </div>
</form>
```